# How to get a URL using routing tables from a Service Class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm writing a asp.net MVC 5 app, and have a service class that gets called from the controller.  In the service I'm loading a DTO based on some queried data and would like to build a URL using routing similar to how I do in my Razor code.
@Url.Action("RequestData", "Home", new {area = "MyArea"})

How can I get MVC to build my URL using the routing tables from a class without access to the base controller class?

Example:

```
public class MyDataService : IMyDataService
{
   private readonly MyDataContext _context;

public MyDataService()
: this(new MyDataContext())
{
}

public MyDataService(MyDataContext ctx)
{
   if (ctx != null)
      _context = ctx;
}

public List<MyDTO> LoadDTOInfo(int id)
{
   var people = _context.People.ToList();
   var list = new List<MyDTO)();    

   foreach(var person in people)
   {
      var dto = new MyDto{
      MyUrlLink = ...??? // controller/action/+person.Id;
   };       

   list.add(dto);
   }        
   return list;  
}
```

}

using @alisabzevari ANSWER:

UrlHelper helper = new UrlHelper();

helper.Action("ActionName","Controller", new{area = "area"});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instantiate a `UrlHelper` class. `Url` at razor view and controller are both an instance of `UrlHelper` class. This class have `Action` method and you can use it to generate urls based on routing.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see the parameterless ctor on UrlHelper.